# PHP Random Color select

Tags: php

I am writing `randomColorSelect()` function, so that when the script is executed, prints the word `RED` 10% of the time, the word `BLUE` 50% of the time and the word `GREEN` 80% of the time: but not getting how to get this as i am new in PHP.

Comment: Do you have any code to start with?

Comment: 80% + 50% + 10% = 140%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

This should give the desired effect.

```
$red_dice = rand(0, 100); // 0% to 100%
$blue_dice = rand(0, 100); // 0% to 100%
$green_dice = rand(0, 100); // 0% to 100%

if ($red_dice <= 10)
{
     echo "RED\n";
}

if ($blue_dice <= 50)
{
     echo "BLUE\n";
}

if ($green_dice <= 80)
{
     echo "GREEN\n";
}
```

Comment: This could print `RED`, `BLUE` and `GREEN` in one execution, i'm guessing that's not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Peter I'd thought of that, but 10% + 50% + 80% = 140% so there will HAVE to be some overlap.

Comment: It could also print nothing... ;) And I suppose there's a typo in the numbers or something.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the believe that the percentages should add up to 100% total:

```
$number = rand(1, 100);
// 10%
if($number <= 10)
{
     echo 'RED';
}
// 50%
else if(($number >= 11) && ($number <= 60))
{
    echo 'BLUE';
}
// rest-%, in this case 30
else
{
    echo 'GREEN';
}
```